# Using SQLAlchemy ORM-like style, but async

Tags: python, asynchronous, sqlalchemy

Using SQLAlchemy ORM style with Async

I'm used to do sql requests with SQLAlchemy orm-styled request, like

```
with Session(bind=engine) as db:
    users = db.query(User).all()
```

How i can do the same, but in async version? Tried to hard-googling, but only what i found is like
`db.execute(select(User))`